# why is python scapy.srp1 returning the packet I sent instead of the response?

Tags: python, windows-10, scapy, raw-ethernet

I'm trying to use the scapy package inside of python (3.10), on Windows 10, to communicate with an embedded device over raw ethernet. When I send the device a raw packet (level 2) using the srp1 function, the value returned is the original packet I sent, rather than the response from the device.

Here's my code (the first part just locates the interface to use):

```
from scapy.arch.windows import *
from scapy.all import *

def get_if():
        for info in get_windows_if_list():
                if (info['description'] == 'Linksys USB3GIGV1'):
                        for k,v in info.items():
                                if (k == 'name'):
                                        name = v
                                elif (k == 'mac'):
                                        mac = v
        return (name, mac)

(interface, src_addr) = get_if()
etherType = 0x1234
dst_addr = b"\xfc\xee\xdd\xcc\xbb\xaa"
payload = bytearray.fromhex("2a0000001234567820200100") + bytearray(34)
packet = Ether(src=src_addr, dst=dst_addr, type=etherType)/payload
rsp = srp1(packet, iface=interface)
hexdump(packet)
hexdump(rsp)
```

When I monitor the interface with Wireshark, I can see the correct outgoing and response packets. But the script prints the following:

> Begin emission:
> Finished sending 1 packets.
>
> Received 1 packets, got 1 answers, remaining 0 packets
>
> 0000  FC EE DD CC BB AA 24 F5 A2 F1 BE C1 12 34 2A 00  ......$......4*.
> 0010  00 00 12 34 56 78 20 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...4Vx  ........
> 0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> 0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              ............
>
> 0000  FC EE DD CC BB AA 24 F5 A2 F1 BE C1 12 34 2A 00  ......$......4*.
> 0010  00 00 12 34 56 78 20 20 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ...4Vx  ........
> 0020  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> 0030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              ............

As you can see, the response is the same as the sent packet.

I have some Java code (that uses npcap) that successfully communicates with the device, so I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong with scapy and/or python.